# quit 'code' command on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I typed `code index.html` which opened my visual studio code. I am trying to exit the command but it's not working. I have tried ctrl + q, ctrl+ c and q but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ps aux | grep code` to show the pid (process id) of the `code` process in the second column of the output.
2. Run `kill the_pid_number_that_you_found_in_step_1` to close the VSCode window.